# How to fix unpickling key error when loading word2vec (gensim)?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to load a pre-trained word2vec model in pkl format taken from [here](https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/)

The line of code I use to load it:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load('enwiki_20180420_500d.pkl')
```

However, i keep getting the following error (full traceback):

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ebd5780b6636> in <module>
     55 
     56 #Load pretrained word2vec
---> 57 model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load('enwiki_20180420_500d.pkl',mmap='r')
     58 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
   1551     @classmethod
   1552     def load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs):
-> 1553         model = super(WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
   1554         if isinstance(model, FastTextKeyedVectors):
   1555             if not hasattr(model, 'compatible_hash'):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
    226     @classmethod
    227     def load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs):
--> 228         return super(BaseKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
    229 
    230     def similarity(self, entity1, entity2):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in load(cls, fname, mmap)
    433         compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    434 
--> 435         obj = unpickle(fname)
    436         obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    437         logger.info("loaded %s", fname)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in unpickle(fname)
   1396         # Because of loading from S3 load can't be used (missing readline in smart_open)
   1397         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
-> 1398             return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
   1399         else:
   1400             return _pickle.loads(f.read())

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ':'.
```

I tried loading it with load_word2vec_format, but no luck. Any ideas what might be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your link https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/ these are to be loaded using that library's `Wikipedia2Vec.load()` method.

Gensim's `.load()` methods should only be used with files saved directly from Gensim model objects.

The Wikipedia2Vec project does say that their `.txt` file formats would load with `.load_word2vec_format()`, so you could also try that - but with one of their `.txt` format files.

Their full model `.pkl` files are only going to work with their class's own loading function.